# How I can use LCDUI from LWUIT app?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lcdui, nokia-s40

I want to use standard alerts dialog (as LCDUI) in my LWUIT app: [lcdui Alert javadocs](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/_zip/GUID-0D0A1092-5037-4421-B466-B958CB777414/javax/microedition/lcdui/Alert.html)

How can I call this methods from LWUIT form?

Comment: Are you sure this is possible?

Comment: I don't know, I hope someone know it.

Comment: Why don't you use the LWUIT Dialogs?

Comment: I want alerts look as default alerts on the platform (nokia s40 2.0).

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but a bit long process.

Comment: Could you please provide me some links or other informations about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LWUIT's 1.5's `Display` has the method `showNativeScreen`.

I wouldn't recommend doing this though, it would probably cause some issues.

To return to LWUIT just show a `Form`.

Comment: I tried using this method but I get the following exception when i am trying to dismiss the alert on click of a button.: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Current Displayable is an Alert"